# Scraping documents from climate change website PYTHON

Tags: python, web-scraping

I need to get files from the European Space Agency (ESA) website which allows to choose latitude, longitude and years and once those gaps are filled in you can click on "download" and get the specific file you asked for.

I need to retrieve data from  a range of coordinates and a set of years would like to do it on python.  The website's code uses "id" and not "name" to identify the variables (lat, lon, years)

link: http://www.esa-sst-cci.org/PUG/map.htm

Thank you

Comment: There are lots of sites on the web where you can post a requirement and someone will write the code for you (for a fee) unfortunately this is not one of them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: and what is a problem? show in question your code and FULL error message (Traceback)

Comment: BTW:use DevTools (tab "Network") in Chrome/Firefox to see how browser sends this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Selenium WebDriver. It is can make direct call to the browsers using browser's native support for automation.

Click [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example)
Introducing Selenium webdriver api by example